# Call multiple `setState` hooks from multiple successive async calls in a for loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-functional-component

I have the following functional React component:

```
const MyComp = (props) => {
  const [dict, setDict] = useState({});

  const myFunc = () => {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(x => {
      fetch('something' + x)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          setDict({...dict, [x]: res.y}); // <--------   PROBLEMATIC HERE
        })
    });
  }
}
```

It seems like React is pre-optimizing this, so all of my `setDict` calls are mushed into one. This means that the `dict` only has the one arbitrary result of the multiple callbacks. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you explicitly explain what result do you want to achieve? I don't quite get what you mean

Comment: Well, I made multiple API calls in the for loop, and I want to have all of the result stored in my `dict`, but as I said in the question, React seems to suppress the multiple `setDict`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Issue

You are enqueueing state updates in a loop using a standard update. This means each update uses the state from the render cycle the update is enqueued in. Each subsequent update overwrites the previous state update, so the net result is the last enqueued update is the one that sets state for the next render cycle.

## Solution

Use a functional state update. The difference here is that functional state updates updates from the previous state, not the state from the previous render cycle. It requires only a minor tweak from `setDict({...dict, [x]: res.y})` to `setDict(dict => ({...dict, [x]: res.y}))`.

```
const MyComp = (props) => {
  const [dict, setDict] = useState({});

  const myFunc = () => {
    [1, 2, 3].forEach(x => {
      fetch('something' + x)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          setDict(dict => ({...dict, [x]: res.y}));
        })
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` provides your state's current value in the first argument of the callback

So use `dict` value from callback argument rather than state value of `dict`

```
const MyComp = (props) => {
const [dict, setDict] = useState({});

const myFunc = () => {
  [1, 2, 3].forEach(x => {
    fetch('something' + x)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        setDict((dict) => {...dict, [x]: res.y}); // <--------   PROBLEMATIC HERE
      })
  });
}
```